# Unexpected behaviour when comparing GUIDs in .NET

Tags: c#, lambda, comparison, extension-methods, guid

I have attempted to create an extension method that looks like this...

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Distinct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> value, IEnumerable<T> compareTo, Func<T, object> compareFieldPredicate)
{
    return value.Where(o => !compareTo.Exists(p => compareFieldPredicate.Invoke(p) == compareFieldPredicate.Invoke(o)));
}
```

The idea is that I would be able to do something like this...

```
IEnumerable<MyCollection> distinctValues = MyCollection.Distinct(MyOtherCollection, o => o.ID); //Note that o.ID is a guid
```

Now at this point I would have expected to have only my distinct items returned to me but what I found is that this was never the case.

Upon further research breaking down this method using the following code.

```
Guid guid1 = Guid.NewGuid();
Guid guid2 = new Guid(guid1.ToString());

Func<MyObject, object> myFunction = o => o.ID;
Func<MyObject, object> myFunction1 = o => o.ID;

bool result = myFunction(MyObject) == myFunction1(MyObject);
//result = false
```

I have found that infact even if the Guids are the same the comparison will always return false.

What is the cause of this?

Comment: A custom class that contains a field ID of type guid. Sorry if that wasnt clear...

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if it's a type, why are you passing it into `myFunction` or `myFunction1`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you're boxing the Guids into Objects before you compare them. Consider this code:

```
Guid g1 = Guid.NewGuid();
var g2 = g1;

Console.WriteLine(g1 == g2);

object o1 = g1;
object o2 = g2;

Console.WriteLine(o1 == o2);
```

That actually outputs:

```
true
false
```

Since "o1" and "o2", while equal to the same Guid, are not the same object.

If you truly want your "Distinct" extension method to not be tied to a specific type (like Guid), you can do this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TItem> Distinct<TItem, TProp>(this IEnumerable<TItem> value, IEnumerable<TItem> compareTo, Func<TItem, TProp> compareFieldPredicate)
    where TProp : IEquatable<TProp>
{
    return value.Where(o => !compareTo.Any(p => compareFieldPredicate(p).Equals(compareFieldPredicate(o))));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the concise answer. I figured it might be something along those lines but didnt understand it 100%. The Equatable generic constraint is a really nice touch BTW.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool result = (guid1==guid2); //result -> true
```

You can try to change return type Object to GUID in myfunction and myfunction1

```
Func<MyObject, Guid> myFunction = o => o.ID;
Func<MyObject, Guid> myFunction1 = o => o.ID;
```

Otherwise, the return value (true) is boxed to Object, and Reference equality is checked, which is false.

Answer (score 1):

Change to use

```
Func<MyObject, Guid> myFunction = o => o.ID;
Func<MyObject, Guid> myFunction1 = o => o.ID;
```

It's because your function was defined as

```
Func<MyObject, object>
```

The Guid returned by `myFunction` and `myFunction1` will be boxed in two different obejcts.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) for boxing and unboxing feature in .NET

Therefore, when the comparison was done, two different objects are compared.

The default implementation of `Equals` in object is doing reference equality check.  It's not checking the boxed values.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) for more details on how object.Equals implemented.

Comment: That's how I was going to phrase my answer, but since the two returned objects are the same reference it is not clear to me why it returns false. However, changing them to Guid fixes it anyway.

Comment: @Michael The Guid returned by `myFunction` and `myFunction1` are going to be boxed in two different objects.  See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, your `compareFieldPredicate` returns an `object` and its operator `==`  uses `object.ReferenceEquals`, rather than `object.Equals`, so your code always checks for object identity rather than equality.

One solution to this would be to use `object.Equals` method instead of operator `==`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Distinct<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> value, 
    IEnumerable<T> compareTo, 
    Func<T, object> compareFieldPredicate
)
{
    return value.Where(o => !compareTo.Exists(
        p => object.Equals(compareFieldPredicate(p), compareFieldPredicate(o))
    ));
}
```

A better solution uses the default comparer for the actual key type, eliminating boxing if the type implements `IEquatable` interface for itself:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Distinct<T, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<T> value, 
    IEnumerable<T> compareTo, 
    Func<T, TKey> compareFieldPredicate
)
{
    return value.Where(o => !compareTo.Exists(
        p => EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default.Equals(compareFieldPredicate(p), compareFieldPredicate(o))
    ));
}
```

However, most of the functionality of your `Distinct` method is already implemented by
[`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx) LINQ method.

You can rewrite your implementation in terms of [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx) by providing an implementation of `IEqualityComparer`:

```
private class KeyEqualityComparer<T, TKey> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, TKey> _keySelector;

    public KeyEqualityComparer(Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
    { _keySelector = keySelector; }

    public int GetHashCode(T item)
    { return _keySelector(item).GetHashCode(); }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    { return EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default.Equals(_keySelector(x), _keySelector(y)); }
}

public static IEnumerable<T> ExceptBy<T, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<T> first, 
    IEnumerable<T> second, 
    Func<T, TKey> keySelector
)
{
    return first.Except(second, new KeyEqualityComparer<T, TKey>(keySelector));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the lambda to return a Guid, then it works:

```
Func<MyObject, Guid> myFunction = o => o.ID;
Func<MyObject, Guid> myFunction1 = o => o.ID;
```